# How to access keys in LinkeHashMap<String, ArrayList>?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

`LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

How to access keys?
As using :

```
for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet())
```

Gives error as:
**The method entrySet() is undefined**

Comment: Works for me. Can you share a full snippet and the exact error message?

Comment: If you only want the keys use `map.keySet()`.

Comment: also, dont use raw types. use generics. `Entry<Foo, Bar>`